# List ordering based on dict key value with string number

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a simple `list` of `dict` objects that I would like to order based on the values of the `number` keys. I could find here a solution that worked properly until I had values between `0-99`, but since there are 3 char long strings it doesn't work anymore.

It looks my base list:

```
base_list = [{'number':"123", 'key2':"sample value"},{'number':"3", 'key2':"sample value"},{'number':"55", 'key2':"sample value"},{'number':"43", 'key2':"sample value"},]
```

And this is what I would like to achive:

```
base_list = [{'number':"3", 'key2':"sample value"},{'number':"43", 'key2':"sample value"},{'number':"55", 'key2':"sample value"},{'number':"123", 'key2':"sample value"},]
```

And this is what I got:

```
base_list = [{'number':"123", 'key2':"sample value"},{'number':"3", 'key2':"sample value"},{'number':"43", 'key2':"sample value"},{'number':"55", 'key2':"sample value"},]
#123,3,43,55 instead of 3,43,55,123
```

I assume the problem is the values that I use for sorting the list are strings, but unfortunately I can't use integers.

Is it possible to solve the problem without int type values? Or it's not a problem?

This is how I'm doing it now:

```
sortedList = sorted(base_list, key=itemgetter('number'))
```

Comment: Your key function sorts the list literally. Convert the number to `int` in order to get a proper result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort not in-place, use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) instead of [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists),

```
base_list = [{'number':"123", 'key2':"sample value"},{'number':"3", 'key2':"sample value"},{'number':"55", 'key2':"sample value"},{'number':"43", 'key2':"sample value"},]

result = sorted(base_list, key=lambda x: int(x['number']))

print(result)
# Output
[{'key2': 'sample value', 'number': '3'}, {'key2': 'sample value', 'number': '43'}, {'key2': 'sample value', 'number': '55'}, {'key2': 'sample value', 'number': '123'}]
```

Comment: duplicate answer to Vedang Mehta

Comment: @piRSquared, I just saw his answer after I posted. His answer sorted the list in place, but I am not. Should I delete it?

Comment: I'm not a mod, but I would.

Answer (score 4):

Code -

```
base_list = [
    {'number': "123", 'key2': "sample value"},
    {'number': "3", 'key2': "sample value"},
    {'number': "55", 'key2': "sample value"},
    {'number': "43", 'key2': "sample value"}
]


base_list.sort(key=lambda d: int(d['number']))

print(base_list)
```

Output -

```
[{'key2': 'sample value', 'number': '3'}, {'key2': 'sample value', 'number': '43'}, {'key2': 'sample value', 'number': '55'}, {'key2': 'sample value', 'number': '123'}]
```

Comment: I was just about to hit button to post this exact solution.  ;-) upvoted